# Formal/informal word for "something which is hard to deal with"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, idiom-meaning

Is there any formal/informal word which possibly reflects the meaning of "something which is hard to deal with"?

Comment: difficult, entangled, complex, complicated,...

Comment: what about FUBAR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intractable?

> hard to control or deal with

via Oxford (here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/intractable).

Answer (score 0):

An acronym: PITA. "Pain in the..."

Another one on the the crude and un-PC side: "bitch".

Answer (score 0):

Somebody or something hard, or difficult, to deal with is informally referred to as tough: a tough customer (difficult to sell to), a tough steak (difficult to chew), a tough question (difficult to solve), a tough negotiator, tough love, etc.